# How to do match between two different data frame using str_detect?

Tags: r, string, merge, match

I have to match the data with two different dataframe .

```
    structure(list(V1 = c(100270L, 100271L, 100273L, 101058L, 101159L, 
    101210L, 101211L, 101227L, 101228L, 101229L, 101230L, 101231L
    ), V2 = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 
    4L), .Label = c("Doyne honeycomb retinal dystrophy", "Erythrocytosis, familial, 2", 
    "Hereditary cancer-predisposing syndrome", "Li-Fraumeni syndrome", 
    "Primary Microcephaly, Recessive", "Von Hippel-Lindau syndrome"
    ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -12L))

x <- as.vector(data$V2)
    pattern <- c("cancer-predisposing syndrome" , "Von Hippel-Lindau" , "Erythrocytosis"  , "Primary Microcephaly", "Doyne honeycomb retinal dystrophy")
     str_detect( x ,coll(pattern))
```

After this:

```
>  str_detect( x ,coll(pattern))
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
**Warning message:
In stri_detect_coll(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_collator = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length**
```

I want to match data with mut and if it match than I want value present in data$V1.
Right now the output str_detect is wrong.

My actual data has 25267 rows and mut has 800 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The function `str_detect` expects a single pattern, not multiple patterns. You could use the package *fuzzyjoin*:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

mut <- data.frame(pattern=c("cancer-predisposing syndrome" , "Von Hippel-Lindau" , "Erythrocytosis"  , "Primary Microcephaly", "Doyne honeycomb retinal dystrophy"))
data <- data.frame(V1 = c(100270L, 100271L, 100273L, 101058L, 101159L, 101210L, 101211L, 101227L, 101228L, 101229L, 101230L, 101231L),
                   V2 = c("Doyne honeycomb retinal dystrophy", "Erythrocytosis, familial, 2", "Hereditary cancer-predisposing syndrome", "Li-Fraumeni syndrome", "Primary Microcephaly, Recessive", "Von Hippel-Lindau syndrome")
)

data %>% regex_inner_join(mut, by=c("V2"="pattern")) %>% select(V1)
```

Comment: Thankyou. This works with example data but when I run this, on full data it does not match properly.[no error while running]

Comment: If you could describe what is not matching properly Someone might be able to help.

Comment: hey , I have solve the issue . Thankyou . their some NAN  and  special characters in raw data , I just clean it and it works.